# Why doesn't global eval work in this case?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn JavaScript from [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide 6th ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527) On page 81, the author explains that there is a difference if you call `eval` by its original name, as opposed to when you create a different name. The author illustrates with the following source code:

```
var geval = eval;               // Using another name does a global eval
var x = "global", y = "global"; // Two global variables

function f()  // This function does a local eval
{
    var x = "local";            // Define a local variable
    eval("x += 'changed';");    // Direct eval sets local variable
    return x;                   // Return changed local variable
}

function g()  // This function does a global eval
{
    var y = "local";            // A local variable
    geval("y += 'changed';");   // Indirect eval sets global variable
    return y;                   // Return unchanged local variable
}

console.log(f(), x); // Local variable changed: prints "localchanged global":
console.log(g(), y); // Global variable changed: prints "local globalchanged":
```

I tried to execute the code and I get:

```
/usr/bin/node test.js

localchanged global
undefined:1
y += 'changed';
^
ReferenceError: y is not defined
    at eval (eval at g (/home/martin/Projects/WebPages/test.js:18:5), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at g (/home/martin/Projects/WebPages/test.js:18:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/martin/Projects/WebPages/test.js:23:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Please, could you explain, why the `y` variable is not visible in the call to `geval`?

Comment: Read http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: It works in a browser, so it seems like this is something specific to Node.js.